# How to determine if the MethodInfo is an override of the base method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, overriding, methodinfo

I'm trying to determine if the MethodInfo object that I get from a GetMethod call on a type instance is implemented by the type or by it's base.

For example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
MethodInfo methodInfo = foo.GetType().GetMethod("ToString",BindingFlags|Instance);
```

the ToString method may be implemented in the Foo class or not.  I want to know if I'm getting the foo implementation?

> **Related question**
>
> [Is it possible to tell if a .NET virtual method has been overriden in a derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839984/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-a-net-virtual-method-has-been-overriden-in-a-derived-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check its `DeclaringType` property.

```
if (methodInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(Foo)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the inspected method is also an abstract one. Here is the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560768/5259296).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using reflection a much faster way is to use delegates!
Especially in the new version of the framework the operation is really fast.

```
    public delegate string ToStringDelegate();

    public static bool OverridesToString(object instance)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            ToStringDelegate func = instance.ToString;
            return (func.Method.DeclaringType == instance.GetType());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic! I haven't seen this trick anywhere before. How did you come up with it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the DeclaringType property. If the ToString method comes from Foo, then the DeclaringType will be of type Foo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `DeclaringType` property of `MemberInfo` object (*`DeclaringType` actually gets the class that declares this member*) **is equal to** `ReflectedType` property (*which gets the class object that was used to obtain this instance of `MemberInfo`*).

Besides that, you have also to check the property **`IsAbstract`**. **If** it is `true`, **then** the inspected method is definitely **not overridden**, because "being abstract" means that this member is a new declaration that cannot have it's implementation (*body*) within current class (but only in derived classes instead).

Here is an example of usage of the extension method provided below:

```
Student student = new Student
{
    FirstName = "Petter",
    LastName = "Parker"
};

bool isOverridden = student.GetType()
    .GetMethod(
        name: nameof(ToString),
        bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
        binder: null,
        types: Type.EmptyTypes,
        modifiers: null
    ).IsOverridden(); // ExtMethod

if (isOverridden)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(student);
}
```

Extension Method:

```
using System.Reflection;

public static class MethodInfoHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Detects whether the given method is overridden.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">The method to inspect.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true" /> if method is overridden, otherwise <see langword="false" /></returns>
    public static bool IsOverridden(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return methodInfo.DeclaringType == methodInfo.ReflectedType
               && !methodInfo.IsAbstract;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually a method **can** reabstract, i.e. be `abstract override`.
([sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEDMACFAmDAhaOAYQBtooBYAKAG9qMGtMA3ASwRgFcISsAWDAGUA9mDgBZODAAWwgCYAKAJT1GdKowwBfajqrV0GCMFgIIAYxhZcAJTjHTFmKwB2Ac1LkMIfIU9RKWlUGQwcYM0sMYWZEBFY5OH4hUQkpWUUlAG5dIA===))

Comment: Maybe you're talking about something different though– OP asked how to detect that a method is an override, not how to detect that a method is overridden.

Comment: Regarding abstract methods: Let's say `Animal` overrides `ToString()`, and `Mammal` then has an `abstract override` of `ToString()`. In other words, `Mammal` _re-abstracts_ the method, requiring that its concrete subtypes re-implement it at some point. Would we consider the method to be overridden from the perspective of `Mammal`? It depends on our definition, of course. One thing we can say for sure is that the method is definitely overridden compared to the _original_ implementation (which happens to be `Object.ToString()`).