# Determine if Equals() is an override?

Tags: c#, reflection, testing, overriding, equals

I have an instance of Type (type).  How can I determine if it overrides Equals()?

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: I'm just playing w/ Reflection and can't figure it out.  I've spent my time budget, but I'm punting to the smart people now.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982347/how-to-determine-if-the-methodinfo-is-an-override-of-the-base-method

Comment: @Matti - Unit testing perhaps?  It can be useful to know if a type *should* override Equals(), but hasn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private static bool IsObjectEqualsMethod(MethodInfo m)
{
    return m.Name == "Equals"
        && m.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(object));
}

public static bool OverridesEqualsMethod(this Type type)
{
    var equalsMethod = type.GetMethods()
                           .Single(IsObjectEqualsMethod);

    return !equalsMethod.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(object));
}
```

Note that this reveals whether `object.Equals` has been overridden *anywhere* in the inheritance hierarchy of `type`. To determine if the override is declared on the type itself, you can change the condition to

```
equalsMethod.DeclaringType.Equals(type)
```

EDIT:
Cleaned up the `IsObjectEqualsMethod` method.

Comment: I'm curious why you use the Linq with the IsObejectEqualsMethod when you could call type.GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(object } )

Is there some benefit or behavior I'm missing?  Or is it just to be Linq-y?

Comment: @Hounshell: For a second, I was wondering why myself, but I just remembered. If the type contains a hiding `public new bool Equals(object obj)`, we would be reasoning about the wrong method. I agree the current technique I am using to deal with this is not great, but do you know of a better solution?

Comment: Great answer. Much shorter than my own, and still passes all my strange test cases. Tests with method hiding: http://nopaste.info/bd9b052f8d_nl.html

Answer (score -1):

If you enumerate all methods of a type use BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly so you won't see methods which you just inherited but not have overridden.

Comment: Except that with `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` you will _also_ not see methods which _have_ been overridden. The override is not considered to be a "declaration" of the method per se; the member can be declared just once, in the least-derived type where it appears. In other words: this answer completely fails to address the question.