# How to check if method is overridden inside a type ? Reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if Equals() is an override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629605/determine-if-equals-is-an-override)

I need to run specific pieces of code for whether a specific type overrides `Object.Equals` or not.

How can I check if a type overrides this method?

Typing `typeof(mytype).GetMethod("Equals").` in VS brings me a wide list of options, but there's no "IsOverriden" or something like that.

Comment: The point of polymorphism is that you don't have to care whether a class overrides methods like `Equals` -- if it does, then you trust it to do the right thing.  To even care, smells.

Comment: Do you want to know if *that* type overrides the method, or if any of its base classes overrides?

Comment: @cHao he could be crafting a framework that uses reflection over types that need to implement a custom Equals. It is common in WPF.

Comment: @Ani in fact, it sounds like an exact duplicate, should I delete it ? I tried searching before but it seems I failed.

Comment: @cHao has a good point, do you really REALLY have to check this? I suppose there are some reasonable use cases but they are rare and far in between, maybe there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Conrad: No don't delete it. The moderators will leave as is/merge/delete as they deem appropriate.

Comment: Yeah I don't think this should be deleted if it is easier to find.

Comment: @cHao I'm comparing two objects of specific types, I'll call equals if they override it or are primitives/string/date/etc, or compare them memberwise if they do not.

Comment: @Conrad: If those specific types can be "equal" valuewise without being *equal* according to `Object.Equals`, then they should override `Equals`.  If they don't, then you generally shouldn't care whether they have the same values, because nothing else in the framework will treat them as equal.

Comment: @cHao I can't find a good way to do this. I'm using roslyn ctp to compare two pieces of code, then crawl inside a method and retrieve a report of all changes. But instead of comparing each object separately, I'm crawling into the objects inside `MethodDeclarationSyntax` and checking if they're equal.

Comment: I'm generally no friend of deleting questions, but since this one does not contain a correct answer, and the duplicate does, I think it's appropriate here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the binding flags to your advantage:

```
var t = typeof(mytype).GetMethod(
            "Equals",
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
        );
```

Then `t` is not `null` if and only if `mytype` overrides `Equals`.

Comment: Your code doesn't even work for `string` and most other types that override equals because it hits an `AmbiguousMatchException` because these types overload `Equals`. And it doesn't take care of method hiding either. Check Ani's answer on the duplicate for a method that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `DeclaringType` is `typeof(object)`.

Comment: Yeah, basically check the DeclaringType of the MethodInfo object returned by GetMethod

Comment: That doesn't help one bit: object has Equals() by default, but it doesn't help to know if it's overriden.

Comment: instance.GetType().GetMethod('MethodName').DeclaringType should help, yes

Comment: @Baboon: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Baboon: Wrong.  The `DeclaringType` for an overriden `Equals` will not be `object`.

Comment: @Baboon: From MSDN: "If the Type object from which this MemberInfo object was obtained did not declare this member, the DeclaringType property will represent one of its base types."  That means if the the thingie exists in `Object` and no class along the inheritance chain overrides it, `DeclaringType` will return `Object`'s type.

Comment: You can construct strange types for which this doesn't work. Method hiding is a strange beast.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, first the `MethodInfo` class has a `DeclaringType` you can use to see if it is `System.Object`. Second you can use the overloads of `GetMethod` that accept a `BindingFlags` enum and pass in `DeclaredOnly` to ensure you don't get any parent objects.