# How to detect current type has "ToString" overrided method or not?

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if the MethodInfo is an override of the base method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982347/how-to-determine-if-the-methodinfo-is-an-override-of-the-base-method)

Normally, when we execute "ToString" method of any complex type it will return current type name like the following string except there is "ToString" overrided method.

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UserRole_D77A004638495805D68478322DF47F48540438D82DC9A5A0E1B0B2A181E4A100

I want some logic to detect current type about this because I try to export data to excel format. But some property of model is complex type that doesn't define "ToString" method. Output of this property is useless for normal user.

[image]

**Thanks,**

Comment: It's almost the same. But the old question is hard to find for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this approach to check whether particular type overrides ToString or not is a little bit brittle. We can solve this in several other ways.

First of all if string representation is **required** you can add additional mixin interface like IObjectDescriptor with one method: string GetDescription. And you can **require** this implentation from every type (and if class is not implements it throw an exception).

Second approach (if we don't want to change existing code base) is use separate helper class that will have one method: ConvertToString:

```
static class ToStringHelper
{
  // We can use Generic method to prevent boxing
  public string ConvertToString(object o)
  {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // using reflection to access all public properties, for example

    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

In both cases your intention and "contract" between you and your clients would be much more clear. In first case you'll throw an exception if type is not implements particular interface, with second approach you'll get at least consistent behavior.

Comment: I agree, this is a much better approach. It also allows you to internationalise your program more easily. I usually treat ToString() as for debug purposes only, since all of our programs have to be internationalised and localised, and ToString() is very much the wrong place to be localising stuff! (I don't mean the use of ToString() with a format specification such as DateTime.ToString(string format) - clearly that IS the right way to localise strings.)

Comment: I know. We can create some logic to handle complex data type or some type like DateTime to generate preferred format. 

However, for general propose feature like export button in any grid control, we don't care about which format will be used to serialized object to string.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the DeclaringType on the methodInfo of to string

```
if (methodInfo.DeclaringType != typeof(YourObject)) {
    ...
}
```

[system.reflection.methodinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx)

Comment: Or `!= typeof(object)` if it's acceptable for e.g. an intermediate class to have defined an override.

Comment: What's about normal class like int, double, Guid, string? Do they  still work?

Comment: You are not changing anything on the behavoir of the ToString() method, only checking some of its properties. You can check if your are checking a value type, if so you do not have to check on the override of ToString().

Comment: This solution is only checking the instance if it is derived. But not an answer of this question.

Answer (score 5):

You can of course do this with reflection.  An alternative approach that might give you what you want and doesn't use reflection is:

```
if (this.ToString() != this.GetType().ToString())
{
    // This Type or one of its base types has overridden object.ToString()
}
```

Note that you probably want to check if the current type or any base type (except object) has overridden `ToString()`.  As a contrived example all types derived from `Exception` return a sensible value from `ToString()` (exception details including stack trace), but not all override `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: You cannot use this.ToString() because sometime there is no data to test.

Comment: @Soul_Master, what do you mean "no data to test".  If you mean you don't have an instance of the Type, why do you care what its ToString() method returns?

Comment: Sometime, I got empty List of someclass that mean you cannot use this.ToString method to compare with its type name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsSubclassOf` object and `DeclaringType` of method.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Name;

    public virtual void Write(string val)
    {
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Address;

    public override void Write(string val)
    {
        base.Write(val);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
Type objType = obj.GetType();
MethodInfo info = objType.GetMethod("Write");
if (objType.IsSubclassOf(info.DeclaringType))
{

    Console.WriteLine("Not Override");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Override");
```