# Determine the classes that overridden a specific method

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose that I have this class :

```
 public class TestBase
 {
     public virtual bool TestMe() {  }
 }
```

and I have these classes that inherits from TestBase

**Class A**

```
public class TestA : TestBase
{
    public override bool TestMe() { return false; }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class TestB : TestBase
{
    public override bool TestMe() { return true; }
}
```

**Class C**:

```
public class TestC : TestBase
{
    // this will not override the method
}
```

I would like to return only Class A and B because they override the Method `TestMe()` , How can I achieve that by creating a method in the Main class ?

```
  public List<string> GetClasses(object Method)
   {
     // return the list of classes A and B .
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if the MethodInfo is an override of the base method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982347/how-to-determine-if-the-methodinfo-is-an-override-of-the-base-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for types that:

1. Extends `TestBase`
2. Declares a `TestMe()` method that's:

   - Virtual
   - Non-abstract

```
var baseType = typeof(TestBase);

foreach(var type in baseType.Assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if(type.IsSubclassOf(baseType))
    {
        var testMethod = type.GetMethod("TestMe");
        if(null != testMethod && testMethod.DeclaringType == type && !testMethod.IsAbstract)
        {
            if(testMethod.IsVirtual)
            {
                // `type` overrides `TestBase.TestM()`
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name + " overrides TestMe()");
            }
            else
            {
                // `type` hides `TestBase.TestM()` behind a new implementation
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name + " hides TestMe()");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that we search types returned by `baseType.Assembly.GetTypes()`, this only works for subclasses defined in the same assembly/project.

To search all loaded assemblies at runtime, use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` to enumerate them all first:

```
foreach(var type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes()))
```